# importing text file data by blocks?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to import every rows that starts with '//', I have tried to extract it with the script below. can anybody check my script please?

[image]

```
formatSpec = '//NFE=%f //ElapsedTime=%f //SBX=%f //DE=%f //PCX=%f //SPX=%f //UNDX=%f //UM=%f //Improvements=%f //Restarts=%f //PopulationSize=%f //ArchiveSize=%f //MutationIndex=%f %*f';
N=1
k = 0;
while ~feof(fileID)
k = k+1;
C = textscan(fileID,formatSpec,N,'CommentStyle','#','Delimiter','\n');
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me how you want the output to look, but here is one possibilitiy:

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'rt');
dataset = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n', 'headerlines', 0);
fclose(fid);
result = regexp(dataset{1}, '//([A-Za-z].*)=([0-9\.].*)', 'tokens');
result = result(cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(x), result));
```

result contains both the type, e.g. NFE or SBX, and the number (albeit in character format).